# issue with privileges on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, apple-m1

I'm a FE Dev wrestling with Postgres for 2 days on my newly installed Mac M1.
First time I installed it postgresql@15 with brew I did the mistake of installing also from here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads.

Right now i have 2 users: -cris(superuser) and -postgres(normal) as you can see in the image.
I can only login with postgres, but I don't have any privileges.

Any advice on how I can connect with superuser?

I tried `brew uninstall postgresql@15` `brew doctor` `brew install postgresql@15`, I tried chatGPT, but no success.

.zshrc

```
# Postgres
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin
export PGDATA=/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try `psql -U cris -h localhost -p 5432 -d postgres` ?

Comment: @MikeOrganek > ChatGPT!!   I'm able to login as cris user now! I'm a bit curios why does it work like this but not as `psql -U cris`?

Comment: When you login with a username but no database name, psql assumes that the database you want to connect to is named like your username, in this case, `cris`.  By specifying `-d postgres`, you connect to the existing (created on installation) database as user `cris`.